rsid seems hard coded to be disabled when in PSK31 or RTTY mode. Only works for other modes
So I asked ARRL about the RSID being sent before they make a bulletin transmission, which they said was on but it was not being sent that I could see before the transmission. The RTTY mode just starts up without the RSID.
They also use MFSK32 or MFSK31 sometimes and I did not see it sent for that either.  If it was sent before transmission my fldigi would line up on the frequency and mode. By watching the TX waterfall I see it is disabled always for rtty, psk31 even when txid is enabled. I also verified it was enabled per the txid state on most all other modes.  I changed modes between some of the wider band oddball modes and it transmitted RSID following the state of the 'soft key' ([x}TXID) or ([ ]TXID) its ignored. But if enabled and an unusual mode is selected then it will go off upon key from another program such as WSPR if running at the same time on the same computer using FLRig to control the radio. But the user manual does not mention this at all.
Then I tried enablement via the macro keys, thouht that would turn it on but not for RTTY45 or PSK31, I verified that.
Is there a way to override this 'rsid tx block in rtty45 or psk31' ?
It seems to be hard coded into the version 4.0.18.
Also: Set TXID on. Set modem to MFSK32. Now key the radio with FLRIG, and it transmits rsid that way too also if FLDIGI is running at the same time as WSPR for example it would send RSID when WSPR tried to transmit via FLRIG.
Thats not in the manual either.
Comments?

Hi! The simplest answer is that the ARRL is incorrect when they say they transmit RsID on their bulletins. By default, RSID is disabled on Fldigi for transmit on CW, BPSK31 and RTTY. If you don't see it in the waterfall, it means they're not sending it. You might try to walk them through Configure->Config Dialog->Configure->IDs->RsID->Transmit modes to have them enable it, but if they're not using Fldigi for RTTY/PSK31, that won't help.
